# How to change top offset of an element using an already defined variable

Tags: javascript

I have a project with a navbar. I found a script that allows me to dynamically change the scroll padding based on the height of the nav container. It's working perfectly so now I would like to add a sticky element right below the nav container. Since the number of buttons in the navbar may wrap (the navbar gets taller) I would like the top offset of the sticky element to be the same as the scroll padding.

The script that's working:

```
const navigation = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation"); /* class name of nav container */
const navigationHeight = navigation.offsetHeight;

document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  "--scroll-padding",
  navigationHeight + "px" /* figures out the height of the nav container and converts the value into pixels to be used for scroll-padding */
);
```

I am using the class `".sticky_faq-headings"` to control the top offset of the element underneath the nav container. How can I dynamically change the TOP value to match the "navigationHeight" determined in the script above?

I know I have to reference the "navigationHeight" again and possibly the `"--scroll-padding"` but I am completely lost.

```
const stickyFAQheadings = document.querySelector(".sticky_faq-headings");
const stickyFAQheadingsOffset = stickyFAQheadings.offsetTop;

document.documentElement.style.top(
  "top",
  navigationHeight + "px" 
);
```

How can I have both in the same JavaScript file?
I would be extremely grateful for any assistance.

Comment: top is not a method.... You have `setProperty()` in the one that is working and `top()` in the one that is not....